# multiprocessing.pool.MaybeEncodingError: Error Sending results

Tags: python-3.x, flask, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Can somone please explain the below error?

> multiprocessing.pool.MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result:
>   '[>]'.
>   Reason: 'NotImplementedError("[E112] Pickling a span is not supported,
>   because spans are only views of parent Doc and can't exist on their
>   own. A pickled span would always have to include its Doc and Vocab,
>   which has practically no disadvantage over pickling the parent Doc
>   directly. So instead of pickling the span, pickle the Doc it belongs
>   to or use Span.as_doc to convert span to a standalone Doc object.")'

Below is my code:

**resume_parser2.py**

```
class Resume_parser2(object):
    inputString = ''
    skill = ['Java']
    def __init__(self, resume):
        self.__matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
        self.__skills = {
            'skills'    : None
        }
        self.__text        = utils.extract_text(self.__resume, os.path.splitext(self.__resume)[1])
        self.__text        = ' '.join(self.__text.split())
        self.__nlp         = nlp(self.__text)
        self.__noun_chunks = list(self.__nlp.noun_chunks)


    def __get_basic_details(self):
        skills = utils.extract_skills(self.__nlp,self.__noun_chunks)
        self.__skills['skills'] = skills
        return

    def check_skills(self):
        skill = ['Java']
        if skill in self.__skills:
            return self.__skills

def filtered_resume(resume):
    parser = Resume_parser2(resume)
    return parser.check_skills

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
    resumes = []
    data = []
    for root, directories, filenames in os.walk('resumes'):
        for filename in filenames:
            file = os.path.join(root, filename)
            resumes.append(file)

    results = [pool.apply_async(filtered_resume, args=(x,)) for x in resumes]
    results = [p.get() for p in results]
```

`utils.extract_text` is function defined to extract text from files and `utils.extract_skills` is extracting the skillset from files. Both these are extracting data.

**Api.py**

```
from resume_parser2 import Resume_parser2
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for,send_from_directory, jsonify
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import json
import multiprocessing as mp
import pandas as pd
import os

direct = 'E:/parsertool/backupresumes'

app = Flask(__name__)

def print_cyan(text):
    print("\033[96m {}\033[00m" .format(text))

def extract_from_directory(directory):
    if os.path.exists(directory):
        pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
        resumes = []            
        for root, directories, filenames in os.walk(directory):
            for filename in filenames:
                extension = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
                if (extension == '.pdf' or extension == '.docx'):
                    file = os.path.join(root, filename)
                    resumes.append(file)
        results = pool.map(filtered_resume, resumes)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        return results
    else:
        return 'Directory not found.'


def filtered_resume(resume):
    parser = Resume_parser2(resume)
    return parser.check_skills


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #files = request.files.getlist('files')
        #folder = dirname(files[0].filename)
        #print(folder)
        return jsonify(extract_from_directory(direct))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here I'm not able to understand the error. Can someone please explain what is that error or how to tackle that?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is quite helpful. Somewhere in your code you try to use pickle to save an object that contains spans. Those spans are probably generated from `self.__nlp = nlp(self.__text)` try to convert the results of `self.__noun_chunks = list(self.__nlp.noun_chunks)` into strings maybe something like this `self.__noun_chunks = [str(x) for x in self.__nlp.noun_chunks]`

Also use your debugger to detect other objects that contain spans and then you try to dump them using pickle.

Answer (score 0):

That code is a bit complicated so I haven't tried to reproduce, but first try changing:

```
def filtered_resume(resume):
    parser = Resume_parser2(resume)
    return parser.check_skills
```

to (note the added parentheses at the end of line 3):

```
def filtered_resume(resume):
    parser = Resume_parser2(resume)
    return parser.check_skills()
```

Longer (possible) explanation:

Python pickles (serializes, essentially) any data passed between processes. So, in this case, the result returned from `filtered_resume` gets pickled before being returned to the original process.

I'm guessing that, without the parentheses at the end of `return parser.check_skills`, the `filtered_resume` function is returning the *method* `check_skills` instead of calling it and returning the results (`self.__skills`). And so Python tries to pickle the `check_skills` function. Pickling methods should be fine, but this one requires pickling the whole `Resume_parser2` object (at least because it includes an explicit reference to `self`, possibly because Python would pickle the object anyways since `check_skills` is part of the object).

Pickling objects, just like methods, should be fine. However, if `nlp` is a reference to a spaCy object (I'm guessing so), then you start running into some of the weirdness that comes with pickling spaCy objects. Again, I'm just guessing, but I assume `__noun_chunks` is a set of spans generated by spaCy, and thus when the `Resume_parser2` object gets pickled, it tries to pickle `__noun_chunks` and spaCy complains because they're spans.

If you make the change I recommend above, it should just try to pickle the `__skills` variable and, assuming it doesn't contain spans, it should pickle fine. If, however, that doesn't work, then the code will have to be updated to get rid of the spans or convert them into spaCy docs (as described in the error message itself)...we can cross that bridge when we come to it.